# Why does my robot rotates to the left even when the goal is in its right?

Tags: ros, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a non holonomic robot, "Seekur Jr."
I set up the navigation stack, and I am using TrajectoryPlannerROS as a base local planner, with DWA set to true.

The path planning and obstacle avoidance works just fine , but when it moves the robot shows an incorrect behavior:
When I set the goal to the right of the robot, it first makes a full turn to the left and then starts moving towards the goal.
However when I set the goal to the left or in front of it, it goes directly there.
So it seems the robot always needs to make a left turn first.

I debugged every part of the project(acml, odom,transformation) and the error doesn't seem to be related to them. I also checked all the parameters and matched them to the default parameters.

I have started to tune the parameters and I believe the error is caused by them however I am not sure which parameter to adjust. I have already followed a tuning guide and used all the default parameters.

I also tried all the solutions on the internet but non worked or solved my problem.

Please guide me on this issue. I have already spent close to two months trying to figure it out.

I'd be glad and thankful to your suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189597/why-does-my-robot-rotates-to-the-left-even-when-the-goal-is-in-its-right?/) by [AmiraJr](https://answers.ros.org/users/19987/amirajr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2014-08-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-08-11**:
Which ROS version are you using? With the turtlebot indigo code this doesn't happen anymore, but I have no hydro installed, so I cannot check.

**Comment by [AmiraJr](https://answers.ros.org/users/19987/amirajr/) on 2014-08-12**:
@jorge That was the problem , I had to set the min_vel_theta to -1.0. Thank you so much, you saved the project

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-08-12**:
Cool. I make an answer so this can be useful for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I remember now that in older navistack configurations there was a problem with min_vel_theta and max_vel_theta parameters, where the former must be negative. Type rosparam get /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_vel_theta to ensure that's not your problem.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0